# Finding the derivatives of sin(x) and cos(x)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

We all know that the following (hopefully):

$$\sin(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\ , \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$\cos(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\ , \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

But how do we find the derivates of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ by using the definition of a derivative and the those definition above?

Like I should start by doing:

$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$

But after that no clue at all.  Help appreciated!

Comment: I think if you're going to use the Taylor series expansion, you're not going to want to do the formal definition of the derivative in line 3. You'll just want to use the general rule $d/dx\,a_nx^n=na_nx^{n-1}$ and the fact that the derivative is additive.

Comment: No we will have to use both, that's why I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: How come the accepted answer changed after 5 years when the user is no longer around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using your definition, if you can prove that you may exchange summation and differentiation, then you may write

$$ {d \over dx} \sin x = {d \over dx} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n {d \over dx} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \\
= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{(2n+1) x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \cos x$$

and similarly for the second identity (be careful and make sure you get the minus sign though - hint: what happens to the first term?).

To prove you may exchange summation and differentiation, it suffices to prove that the second series (the series of derivatives) converges uniformly (locally uniformly is also good). In this case, you may do this by using some easy estimates on the factorial.

Answer (score 3):

First, since we deal with a power series which uniformly convergent in any compact set included in the disc of convergnece, we can switch $\lim$ and $\sum$. We have:
\begin{align}\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^{2n+1}-x^{2n+1}}{h} \\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(2n+1)x^{2n}=\cos(x).\end{align}

Comment: wait how about cosine?  Its denominator is (2n)! and we can't make it back to (2n+1)!

Comment: @user67253 Of course we must simplify $(2n+1)!$ with $(2n+1)$ to find $(2n)!$.

Comment: Wait so how do we show this for cos(x)?

Comment: @user67253 Try to repeat the same method for $\cos(x)$, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Use $\sin(x+h)=\sin(x)\cos(h) + \sin(h) \cos(x)$.

Or more explicit
$$\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}=\frac{\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)}{h}+ \frac{\sin(h)\cos(x)}{h}$$
As 
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(x) (\cos(h)-1)}{h}=0$$
And 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)\cos(x)}{h}=\cos(x)$$ 
you get that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$.

For $\cos$ you get the hint $\cos(x+h)=\cos(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x)\sin(h)$$

Comment: Interestingly enough, I have seen a proof of that using $\sin'=\cos $ and $\cos'=-\sin$!

Comment: I would prove those with the power series

Comment: Well, it depends on your definitions, sure. I find power series messy.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence of the power series is infinity, so you can interchange summation and differentiation.

$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x = \frac{d}{dx} \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n  \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \cos x$

If you wish to use the definition, you can do:

$\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h} = \frac{\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{(x+h)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{h} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\frac{(x+h)^{(2n+1)}-x^{(2n+1)}}{h}$

Then $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^{(2n+1)}-x^{(2n+1)}}{h} = (2n+1)x^{2n}$ (using the binomial theorem).

(Note $(x+h)^p-x^p = \sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{p-k}h^k = p x^{p-1}h + \sum_{k=2}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{p-k}h^k$. Dividing across by $h$ and taking limits as $h \to 0$ shows that $\frac{d}{dx} x^p = p x^{p-1}$.)

Comment: This doesn't use the $\lim_{h\to 0}$ method which @user67253 requested, that's all.

Comment: is it impossible to do this?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: I'm stuck when I'm trying to apply the definition of derivative on $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Comment: I have elaborated the computation of the derivative of $x \mapsto x^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the case that you really need to show it, let's examine a general term in $\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\cdot((x+h)^{2n}-x^{2n})&=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\cdot\left(x^{2n}+2nhx^{2n-1}+\ldots+h^2n-x^{2n}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\cdot h\left(2nx^{2n-1}+[\text{a bunch of stuff depending on h}]\right)
\end{align*}
Then if we divide by $h$ then let $h\to 0$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}&\cdot \left(2nx^{2n-1}+[\text{a bunch of stuff depending on h}]\right)=(-1)^n\frac{2nx^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}
\end{align*}

So there's the derivative of a general term. I think the other answers have finished the rest of the proof.