# How to prove derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$ using power series?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-series

How to prove derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$ using power series?

So $\sin x=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ and $\cos x=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

Then $\cos'(x)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)'=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}=...$

Then I don't to how to go to $\sin x$, could someone help?

Comment: At $n=0$, we have: $$\frac d{dx}\frac{(-1)^0x^{2(0)}}{0!}=\frac d{dx}1=0$$So drop the first term of the series and shift it over a bit.

Comment: I suggest, if you're new to taking derivatives of power series, to write out the actual terms and take the derivative of that instead. As you've written above, there is an error in your derivative. You need to start the series at $n = 1$

Comment: @Kaynex So the first derivative will start at $n=1$ and the second at $n=2$?

Comment: A related older post: [Finding the derivatives of sin(x) and cos(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335284).

Answer (score 2):

If you write down it explicitly:

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}+...$$
and$$(\cos x)'=-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+...=\sin x.$$
The point is that you should drop the $n=0$ term in your expression of derivative.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}a_i=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}a_{i+1} $$

$$\cos (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!} $$
$$=1+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!} $$

$$\cos'(x)=0+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$
$$=-\sin (x ) $$

since $(-1)^n=-(-1)^{n+1} $.

Comment: This works, but as the op appears to be new to power series, it may be less helpful than it could be by explicitly expanding them term by term. It can be confusing working with summation notation before understanding what's going on. Just my two cents