# How can I prove the derivative of $\cos(3x)$ is equal to $-3\sin(3x)$ by series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

How can I prove **the derivative of $\cos(3x) = -3\sin(3x)$** by  **series expansion** (like Taylor series **step by step**. Then prove the $d/dx (e^{3x}\cos(3x)) = 3e^{3x} (\cos(3x)-\sin(3x))$.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR0Jx.jpg)

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/ for information on asking questions here.

Comment: Please include your efforts. What is the taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ and how would you go about differentiating this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$ using power series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314174/how-to-prove-derivative-of-cos-x-is-sin-x-using-power-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we know that
\begin{align*}
\cos 3x &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} (3x)^{2n}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} 3^{2n} x^{2n}
\end{align*}

Taking the derivative (remember, the first term is constant, so taking the derivative removes the constant term, hence we start the series at $n=1$):
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \cos(3x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}3^{2n} \frac{d}{dx}x^{2n}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}3^{2n} (2n) \;\;x^{2n-1}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}3^{2n} x^{2n-1}
\end{align*}
shift index by setting $k=n-1$ or $n=k+1$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \cos(3x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!} 3^{2(k+1)} x^{2(k+1) -1}\\ 
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} 3^{2k+2} x^{2k+1}\\
&= -3 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} 3^{2k+1} x^{2k+1}\\
&= -3 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} (3 x)^{2k+1}
\end{align*}
recall that $\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} x^{2k+1}$ to see that we do indeed get that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \cos(3x) &= -3 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} (3 x)^{2k+1}\\
&= -3 \sin(3x)
\end{align*}

As for your second question, I hope you can figure it out in a similar manner (if you have to do that by series expansions aswell).